# How to change "Medium in partial classes" in OpenModelica for a heatpump

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

**Hello**,

How to redeclare "mediums" and in what type?
I try to integrate a heat pump in my model to replace the resistant heater, but I can't copy-paste the model without this error

> [11] 11:43:37 Traduction Erreur
> [BuildingSystems.Fluid.Sources.BaseClasses.PartialSource: 34:3-34:70]: Medium is partial, name lookup is not allowed in partial classes.

Could you help me and show me how to redeclare please?

Thank you

Comment: Use the new OM 1.16.0-dev.beta4 and you can see the Medium classes in the dialog. Otherwise just edit the text and add the redeclare modification to your heat pump component: "component(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.​Media.​Water.​StandardWater, other modifications)". Of course you can choose any other medium than StandardWater.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385558/how-to-specify-medium-in-openmodelica

Comment: I only have **OM 1.16.0-dev.beta1** where can I find the beta4 ?

Comment: https://build.openmodelica.org/omc/builds/windows/releases/1.16/

Comment: You might also like these tutorials: https://spoken-tutorial.org/tutorial-search/?search_foss=OpenModelica&search_language=English